# debian: impossible to connect to a network, maybe there is a dhcp server in my pc

Tags: linux, networking, connection, debian

I have a problem:

When I try to connect to a network, initially with ifconfig eth2 I get (correctly):

```
eth2 inet addr:192.168.1.56 .... 
inet6 addr: fe80:221:ff:fe96:4598/64
```

but after a few seconds the 102.168.1.56 disappears and after some other seconds disappears the inet6 address too. In this case the network is wireless and no DHCP.

At uni, the connection is a DHCP one. It works for the first few seconds but after it doesn't.

Any possible solution?

Comment: where can I find syslog about this? is it possible that another dhcp server in my computer is active and assign me another address?

Answer (score 0):

Whats this `102.168.1.56`?

`cat /var/log/syslog` will give more info about what happening in the system. Usually it contains large amount of information.

Comment: 192.168.1.56 is the ip address that I have set in /etc/network/interfaces and actived with ifup eth2

Comment: from the log it seems that the I can connect succefully but after there are those avahi-daemon and dhclient that start

Comment: Tried giving the values in System->Administration->network ? Actually giving values there solved my problem. I had the same problem as yours.

Comment: Hi Jestin Joy, sorry for the delay. What have you modified from there? I can modify only the dns and the hosts